# Center Image and Cut Off Edges Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website using twitter bootstrap. I have a preview up here: [preview](http://faithpointdallas.com/gg/)

I am trying to make a full width background slider. If you are previewing at a resolution of above 1100px it looks fine, how i want it to. But you'll notice that if you scale down the browser window, the image stays aligned left rather than centering in the window and cutting off the edges (which is what I want). I have tried to fix this and just can't find a solution. I would appreciate any ideas.

Here is my code for the slider:

```
<!-- Slider Top -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item"><img src="img/backgrounds/01.jpg" alt="graduation gift" /></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/backgrounds/02.jpg" alt="graduation gift" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Slider Top -->

    <!-- Slider Overlay -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 sliderFeature">
                <h1 class="whiteShadow">Primary Heading</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <div class="signUp">
                    <h4>Get Started With GraduationGifts.com</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary full-button">Start a Registry</a><br />
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary full-button">Find a Registry</a>
                    <p class="smallText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Slider Overlay -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    /* Slider */
.carousel {
    position:absolute !important;
}

div.signUp {
    background:url(../img/trans-white.png) repeat;
    border:1px solid #c5c5c5;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
}

.full-button {
    width:92%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
}

p.smallText {
    font-size:11px;
}

.sliderFeature {
    padding-top:20px;
    width:50%;
}

div#myCarousel {
    border-bottom:4px solid #164466;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using this as a base and matching your code to it: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

Comment: would adding `width: 100%` to `#myCarousel` not do the trick?

Comment: No because it does EXACTLY what that link BIlly Moat provided. Which is fine in most cases, but width: 100% will stretch my image. So my graduate girl would look like a clown haha. I'm starting to think this might be something that isn't possible to do easily. Might require some kind of custom jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution at: [center oversized image in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562457/center-oversized-image-in-div) where Guffa offers a jsfiddle.

It helped me set mine up.

To use in bootstrap, create a full width container.
Change the selectors in the provided code to be: the full width container instead of .imageContainer, .carousel instead of .imageCenterer, and .carousel .item img instead of .imageCenterer img.