# how to align images horizontally centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On [this page](http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/why-ross-north/), there are some staff photos.

On an iPad in portrait mode, the staff photos are cut off on the right hand side.

I don't mind them being cut off, but I'd like them aligned center, instead of aligned left.

[image]

Note, I want the image dimensions to be the same, just the alignment shifted to the left to become centered, so that faces show in the middle of the image boundaries.

I've tried the following solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989238/center-align-image-within-div-horizontally):

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

and

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

and

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

but none of these are working.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I understood it wrong. So basically you want to center your oversized image in small div.
So your parent div (Image Parent) is positioned relatively. First of all you don't need lot of css you have written for your image class. Remove all of that from **'ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img'** class.Now your code will look like

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
}
```

Even if you not going to remove your css from image class this will work for all screen widths!
Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673895/center-a-large-image-of-unknown-size-inside-a-smaller-div-with-overflow-hidden?answertab=active#tab-top).You can also position your image relatively in case of *absolute* parent. Don't forget to use *transform*, *moz-transform* for cross browser compatibility as mentioned in link.

Comment: For maintaining aspect ratio you have to add this line also

Comment: max-width:none;

Comment: @Steve Have you checked it?

Comment: Thanks so much @breakit, that fixed it. I ended up setting `top: 85%;`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I checked your css and it's **a complete mess !**
You defenitly should rework it off a bit. All those `!important` statements are terribly wrong practice.

However, I tweaked up a bit your `img` styles and found out a solution that fits your needs.

The trick was to override all the other `width` and `height` styles that applied to your images and simply replace it by a style which only set size of images based on heigth of container.
This solution prevent your images from being distorted.

I also reset the `translate3d` style so the images are centered in container.

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    min-width: auto!important;
    width: auto!important;
    max-width: none!important;
    height: 100%!important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

### Result:

[image: Perfectly fitted images in container, no distortion]

### Edit :

Result @ width: 900px
[image: Still good @ 900px]

It's still good, images are centered and no distortion. However, you could make your divs wider at this breakpoint for a more elegant overall result.

See below for example :
Set the column (`.col-sm-3`) at 50% width and img to `heigth: 120%; max-heigth: none;`

[image: Column at 50% width, img max-heigth none]

### EDIT:

As said in comment, try to put the `<link>` tag of your own css in the end of your `<head>` after all the other stylesheet your site loads.

This will cause your css to be rendered last and your styles to override the previous ones. Then try changing back your rules to those proposed in the explanation above.
This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. The solution does not seem to work when the viewport is 900px wide, which is the critical situation. Can you have a look at your solution with viewport width 900px please?

Comment: Thanks. I have your code @ line 178 of http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/themes/houzez-child/style.css, but I [see this](https://imgur.com/a/Iqpxo). Browser is Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: Okay my bad. The css file I edited is the "ultimate.min.css" which is the css of an add-on you're using. Problem is, this file is loaded AFTER yours and its "!important" statements are making this a dreadfull mess. You should first try to load your css last, then apply the same kind of tweaks we used before to achieve the disered result.

Answer (score 1):

for image you can use:

```css
img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

or you can use Bootstrap

then assign class "img-responsive center-block"

Comment: Thanks Oleg. The images appear stretched vertically now.

Comment: (on [this page](http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/why-ross-north/) in iPad portrait mode)

Comment: I can't mark your answer as solving the problem if the vertical height is stretched now.

Comment: remove width:100%

Comment: `width: 100%;` is not being applied. `width: auto;` is.

Answer (score 1):

I know some of the solutions may work, but there's more to your problems. Its bad practice to insert an inline height or width. Plus you must know the exact size of your image, before you use it. Using image holders help with that. You used the height attribute to make your image smaller. If your image does not fit the container, then you'll always have problems that's why you must always know the exact height and width of the images that your going to use. It also help with performance. On Smaller Screens, there's more issues with your images. The right side is black out simply because of the size of the picture. With responsive design, you want your images to be more square then rectangle, even if its not perfect. The css is a mess, and you are using useless attributes and style properties and values. Simply resize the pictures with a similar width and height of the container (col-sm-3) and then use bootstrap "img-responsive" class and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is only ipad portrait mode and browsers like chrome, safari or firefox, then use object-position.

```
object-position: center center;
object-fit:cover;
```

If you need support in IE or Edge then it wont work in that.

You can mention any position you want, 'center center' is 50% from left and 50% from top.

Kindly clean your code a bit, there are lot of important overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following CSS

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
.ult-new-ib {
    max-height: 330px;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I [see this](https://imgur.com/a/kicJo) when I add your CSS to http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/themes/houzez-child/style.css. My browser is Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have this css code for images

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    width: auto!important;
    max-width: none!important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Add also this three lines

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

And You Win))

Answer (score -1):

Just add following css:

```
.ult-ib-effect-style13.ult-ib2-min-height img {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```