# Center middle part of image within div

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

The image is wider than the surrounding div.
This is for mobil units. The image within the div
has width:auto; and the div holding it is as wide
as the visible area. So if the div is 500px the
image might vary having 1000px or so. But I want
to show the middle part of image only.

Im using an old version of OWL Carousel v1.3.3

```
   <div id="custom-owl-slider" class="owl-slide" data-scroll-speed="2">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_3455.png" alt="">
                </div>
                 <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_771.JPG" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_321.JPG" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_344.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>  
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_563.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>   
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider/IMG_135.jpeg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks!

FIXED with the following:

```
#custom-owl-slider .owl-item  {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    height: auto; /* or other desired height */
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

#custom-owl-slider .owl-item img {
    flex: none !important; /* keep aspect ratio */
}
```

Comment: Post some code so we can try to help

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate some help.

Comment: Please include your CSS and JS as well, so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a large image of unknown size inside a smaller div with overflow hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673895/center-a-large-image-of-unknown-size-inside-a-smaller-div-with-overflow-hidden)? [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fsgd9n87/).

Comment: Yes I got some help there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this for img middle

```
.item > img {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

PD: if you want, this code should fit the image on the div

```
.item > img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That kind of works, but now the image is squeezed to fit the width. I do not want this, I wish to get it only centered showing only the middle horizontal part of image.

Comment: the second code was just if you wanted to made the image fit the container, the first code should solve your problem